# How can I turn a synchronous polling database query into an asynchronous push using reactive extensions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Currently, I'm issuing a database select in NHibernate that returns an `IList` of results. Then I use `IList.ToObservable` on the list returned to get an `IObservable` that I can subscribe to. How can I write this in the reactive paradigm rather than just converting a list to an `IObservable`?

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: Do look at `Observable.Using` for how to back an observable with a disposable resource.

Comment: I'm not sure what's missing from my question? I'll gladly update it with what you think would make it clearer.

Comment: Nothing missing, the issue is you're polling for opinions.  "best way" and "better way" are subjective.

Comment: Oh, I see. I do want opinions though. There are many ways to write this out and while all will work some are more elegant and performant than others. It got a great answer below and I'm sure others could/might come with their alternate ways of doing it as well.

Comment: I see the site has some rules about opinions being bad. While I disagree, I respect the rules and updated my question to align. Hopefully you all agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The very best way to make database calls using Reactive Extensions **is not to do it at all.***

Pithy one-liners aside, this is a serious point. The clue is in the question... you are making an IO bound *call*, therefore you are really in a async pull situation.

There'll be first class language support for this in C# 8 (IAsyncEnumerable - [which already has placeholders in the Rx github repo](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/pull/423)).

But you really don't want to expose a synchronous call response as an Observable when you have initiated a call to which you are expecting a prompt response. Observables are for push scenarios when you don't know if or when data will turn up. You can make your query asynchronous and handle the results more traditionally when they come.

Where you often see async DB queries in Rx is as part of an observable chain rooted in some suitable observable event such as a keypress in a UI. The keypress event is fed into an Observable which in turn projects into an *async* query and is popped back into the UI. e.g: [The example here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/argumentnullexceptionblogpost/2013/06/21/an-rx-enabled-wpf-autocomplete-textbox-part-12/) has a service call that could just as easily be an async DB query. The key part is the use of the `getSuggestions` asynchronous cal and how it is wired in to the observable query.

Note even in this situation the service call itself is still an async pull that is not returning an Observable directly; it's been initiated by some other observed event.

Comment: This is definitely a better way as it uses a non-blocking async call to the database and subscribes to the result when it comes. Thus turning the pull into a push. Observable.FromAsync is the key pattern I was missing!